# Parallelize rocksdb iterator

Tags: c++11, concurrency, iterator, parallel.for, rocksdb

My iterator code:

```
Iterator* iterator = _db->NewIterator(ReadOptions());
for (iterator->SeekToFirst(); iterator->Valid(); iterator->Next()) {
    Slice const& key = iterator->key();
    Slice const& value = iterator->value();
    bool continue = callback(key, value);
    if (!continue) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The order of iterating doesn't matter, but breaking the loop is important so we won't iterate over unneeded elements. I use the fact that the elements are sorted by a meaningful order to know when to break. `callback` can potentially take a long time.

So the pseudo code of what I would like to do is

```
parallel-iterate(iterator)
   if(!callback(key,value)
     stop-parallel
```

I tried to apply concurrency::parallel_for_each, but seems like it won't fit rocksdb api.

How would you suggest to implement concurrent iteration?

Answer (score 3):

I might be mistaken but I think the Iterators in Rocks are not thread-safe, so you would need to use one Iterator per thread. Obviously to have this make sense, you would need to have each Iterator operate over a separate range of the data.

You could either:

1. Count the number of keys and then split the iterator ranges by the number of threads. I believe there is a function for estimating the count.
2. Do an initial scan and decide on a how to divide up your key range
3. Otherwise, if you have some pre-knowledge of your key range, you can decide how to split them without examining the data.

Also, if you want the Iterators to all have the same consistent view, i.e. if there were also concurrent writes occurring, then you should take a Snapshot and create your Iterators from that.